# Transportation Algorithm in Python

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, optimization, scipy, mathematical-optimization

After doing a lot of search on google I am unable to find any transportation algorithm solver in python. I was hoping to find something in Scipy but of no use. Can someone direct me to the right sources?

Idk where to post this question and I know some curator will ask me for the code or say that this is not an appropriate place. In that case please do not forget to direct me to the right place.

My problem:

```
Max(Sum_{i,j}( Cij*Xij) )

x11 + x12 + x13 = D1
X21 + X22 + x23 = D2
X11<10
X23 <100
```

I will have typically 100,000 sinks(creating demand) and around 1000 sources (supplying demands).

Comment: So does that mean that I should formulate this problem as flow problem and solve using one of those libraries? Also since I dont have much experience with any of these libraries, can you suggest some pros and cons of each?

Comment: @YXD: Edited my question. Its a typical Transportation problem.

Comment: What about [this](https://gist.github.com/bogdan-kulynych/7984367)? Although the given answer should also be ok.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to use the technique of **Linear Programming** with the help of [pulp](https://github.com/coin-or/pulp), a python Linear Programming API. The default solver, distributed with pulp, is [cbc](https://projects.coin-or.org/Cbc) (you can switch to commercial ones).

I'm just presenting some code, which fits to your question / problem description ( (a "toy problem"). There are some examples in pulp's github repository.

```
# Import PuLP modeler functions
from pulp import *

# INSTANCE
EDGES = [ (0,10), (0,20), (0,50), (0,30), (0,10), (0,40) ] # lower/upper flow
COSTS = [0.3, 0.7, 0.2, 0.6, 0.2, 0.5]
D1, D2 = [24, 10]

# MODEL
prob = LpProblem("Problem",LpMaximize)
# VARS
x11, x12, x13 = LpVariable("x11", *EDGES[0]), LpVariable("x12", *EDGES[1]), LpVariable("x13", *EDGES[2])
x21, x22, x23 = LpVariable("x21", *EDGES[3]), LpVariable("x22", *EDGES[4]), LpVariable("x23", *EDGES[5])
# OBJECTIVE FUNCTION -> added before constraints => important ,
prob += lpDot(COSTS, [x11,x12,x13,x21,x22,x23]), "Costs"
# CONSTRAINTS
prob += x11 + x12 + x13 == D1
prob += x21 + x22 + x23 == D2

# SOLVE
status = prob.solve()

# PRINT SOLUTION
print LpStatus[status]
for var in [x11,x12,x13]:
    print value(var)
print
for var in [x21,x22,x23]:
    print value(var)
print("Total Costs = ", value(prob.objective))
```

Output:

```
Optimal
4.0
20.0
0.0

10.0
0.0
0.0
('Total Costs = ', 21.2)
```